# What does 누명을 씌워서 mean?

Tags: vocabulary, phrase-meaning

I mostly understand this sentence:

> 이 경우는 사람들이 우리에게 억울하게 "누명을 씌워서" 법정으로까지 끌고 가는 것 이다

To loosely translate my understanding:

> In this situation, people are unfairly "framing" us and dragging us into court.

And I find that "누명을 씌워서" must translate to something like "being framed" (being placed in a situation where one, though innocent, looks guilty).

But what a juicy bunch of vocabulary!  What are the individual semantics...where does this phrase come from, and it does have other connotations and usages that vary from "being framed"?  Can you give me the chinese characters used herein?

Comment: [누명(陋名)](https://krdict.korean.go.kr/eng/dicSearch/SearchView?mainSearchWord=%EB%88%84%EB%AA%85&ParaWordNo=24497&nation=eng)을 씌워서 is not "being framed" but "framing" because [씌우다](https://krdict.korean.go.kr/eng/dicSearch/SearchView?mainSearchWord=%EC%94%8C%EC%9A%B0%EB%8B%A4&ParaWordNo=16738&nation=eng) is a causative verb. 누명을 써서 is "(being) framed."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`누명(陋名)` 陋 means Dirty. 名 means name. So it can be translated as dirty name.

But, it is "Framed name" by other people when you actually didn't do it. So, think Dirty name as some blanket which covers your own name.

That is why people use `누명을 쓰다`, as "framing" as you said. On the other hand, when you uncover the frame and you get your own name back, you can say `누명을 벗다`. I hope it is enough answer :)

Comment: Excellent!  Welcome, btw, and thank you!

Comment: Thank you for welcoming me :) +, we have similar word, `오명(汚名)` here, `오(汚)` also means dirty, but it is little bit different to `누명`. `누명`is used when you got framed even though it is not true, `오명` is used when you did something wrong, so your name got dirty. Such as,`그는 친일파의 아들이라는 오명을 벗어 버리기 위해 다방면으로 노력했다.`(
He made every effort to remove the stigma of being a son of pro-Japanese.) you can also use `오명을 쓰다` `오명을 벗다` as same way.

Comment: + `누(오)명을 입다`, `누(오)명을 씻다` is also valid. I think you can guess what it means

Answer (score 1):

누명 陋名 means, 
a name that is discredited by others 
and a reputation that gets harmed by others' slanders or lies.
It is usually related with serious things such as mistake, sin or crime.

누명 縷命 has different Chinese characters and meaning. 
縷 means a thread and 命 is life. 
So 누명 縷命 means a life that is at stake or in danger like a fine thread. But this meaning is not that commonly used.

씌우다 has several slightly different usages but in most cases, this verb is used as a causative verb of '쓰다' (its basic meaning is 'wear')

1. put a hat on one's head

   > ex) 아이에게 모자를 씌웠다. = put a hat on a child
2. put something on one's face

   > ex) 환자에게 산소카스트를 씌웠다 = put an oxygen mask on the patient
3. put an umbrella over one's head

   > ex) 아이에게 우산을 씌웠다 = put an umbrella on the child
4. make someone seem guilty or falsely accuse someone of being a sinner (this is the meaning that you are asking about)

   > ex) 그들은 그가 스파이라고 누명을 씌웠다 = They accused him of being a spy
   >
   > ex) 그들은 그가 자기 딸에게 잔인한 행동을 했다고 누명을 씌웠다 = They charged him with cruelty to his daughter.

So '씌우다' basically means putting A to or into B.